# Class-calling function not working

Tags: python, class, maya, calling-convention

I am trying to modify this piece of code by calling out a import window then follow by this code.

As I am also going to use the current piece of code (which is not written by me), the way it works is that when user selects one of the 3 prefixes ['a','b','c'], it will change the naming of the items in Maya accordingly.

Part of the former Coding (prefix window):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
import pymel.core as pm
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, os

class createUI(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.shot = SHOT
        self.initUI()
        self.connections()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(400,100)
        self.move(300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Select the prefix of rexPass') 
        self.pubDock = createUI()
        vLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vLayout.addWidget(self.pubDock)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)
        self.createConnection()

    def createConnection(self):
        self.connect( self.pubDock.cancelButton, QtCore.SIGNAL( "clicked()" ), self.close )
        self.connect( self.pubDock.OKButton, QtCore.SIGNAL( "clicked()" ), self.close )

def setupRenderGlobals():
    cmds.setAttr ('StartRange.multiFrame', 1)
    cmds.setAttr ('EndRange.endFrame', 200)
    cmds.setAttr ('WidthRes.xres', 1920)
    cmds.setAttr ('HeightRes.yres', 1080)

def main():
    setupRenderGlobals()
    global app
    app=QtGui.qApp

    global form
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
```

Currently I would like to add on a function where it calls a selection window to import something, and once the selection is done, it will then calls out the above code.

The problem I have is where when user hits the import button in the import window, it automatically closes, and the perfix window is not showing up, or I would have the 2 windows showing up or just the prefix window and not the import window

My Coding:

```
class Processing(): 
'In-house code to call out the import window and they will have the name of 'prItems_a01''
importItems = procureItems.api.importItem()
allItems = pm.ls(type="prItems")


if allItem < 2 :
    test = MainWindow()
else:
    print ('testing')
```

Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

if allItem < 2 :
    test = MainWindow()
else:
    print ('testing')

```
allItems = pm.ls(type="prItems")

if allItem < 2 :
    test = MainWindow()
```

`pymel.core.ls` returns a `list`, while `2` is an `int`. Python may not do what you expect here. [From the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

So, `"list" > "int"`

---

What you probably meant to do is check the `len` of `allItem`, like this:

```
def processing():
    # ~~ your code ~~ #
    if len(allItem) < 2:
        test = MainWindow()
    else:
        print ('testing')
```

Comment: Hi mhlester, thanks, I shall try that out. By the way, is my class being defined properly class Processing()?
Do I need to state anything within the brackets?

Comment: Actually it looks like you intended it to be a `def`. I didn't notice. It's definitely wrong as a `class` but there's no indication it should be one.

Comment: Alright, but I think I tried it out once before by giving it as a `def` instead of `class`, it doesn't seems to be interpreting my coding and it jump right into the `def main()` Will this means I have to change the coding in the `def main()`?

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces. ONLY use spaces, and see if that fixes it. Python has a different interpretation of what's in certain blocks of code than you do